# How do i solve this error TypeError: object of type 'StringVar' has no len()

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Im trying to make a Tkinter program which will use a selenium bot to login for the user after he or she enters a username and a password. However I have a problem with StringVar and len(). I have tried passing .get() to password and username but it just leaves Twitter login and password fields blank.

Heres my error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\blazh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/blazh/Documents/Vladyslav/University/Python/Work.py", line 38, in call
    alex.login()
  File "C:/Users/blazh/Documents/Vladyslav/University/Python/Work.py", line 25, in login
    email.send_keys(self.username)
  File "C:\Users\blazh\Documents\Vladyslav\python\Projects\arcade-games-work\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "C:\Users\blazh\Documents\Vladyslav\python\Projects\arcade-games-work\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'StringVar' has no len()
```

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
import time

#  ============  TWITTER  ===========


class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()


    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://twitter.com/login')
        time.sleep(5)
        email = bot.find_element_by_name('session[username_or_email]')
        password = bot.find_element_by_name('session[password]')
        email.clear()
        password.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)
        password.send_keys(keys.Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(3)

    def logout(self):
        bot = self.bot
        time.sleep(3)
        bot.get('https://twitter.com/logout')


def call():
    alex = TwitterBot(us_verify, ps_verify)
    alex.login()


#  ============  TWITTER  ===========


#  Creating a register window
def register():
    #  Globalising the function/ window
    global register_screen
    #  Defining the window
    register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    register_screen.title("Registration Window")
    register_screen.geometry("500x250")

    #  Globalising the following
    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    #  Creating a StringVar
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    email = StringVar()

    #  Creating labels and packing the
    Label(register_screen, text="Please enter details below", bg="lightyellow").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    username_label = Label(register_screen, text="Username:")
    username_label.pack()
    username_label.place(x=120, y=40)
    email_label = Label(register_screen, text="Email:")
    email_label.pack()
    email_label.place(x=120, y=95)

    #  Creating Entry boxes
    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack(pady=5)

    #  Creating labels and packing them
    password_label = Label(register_screen, text="Password:")
    password_label.pack()
    password_label.place(x=120, y=70)

    #  Creating Entry box
    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()

    #  Creating Entry box
    email_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=email)
    email_entry.pack(pady=5)

    #  Creating labels and packing them
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="lightgreen",     
command=register_user).pack()


#  Creating a login window
def login():
    #  Globalising it
    global login_screen

    #  Defining the window
    login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    login_screen.title("Login Window")
    login_screen.geometry("500x250")
    #  Creating a main label
    Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to continue").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

    #  Globalising the following
    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    #  Creating StringVar for the following
    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    #  Globalising the following
    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry

    #  Creating a label and packing it
    login_username = Label(login_screen, text="Username: ")
    login_username.pack()
    login_username.place(x=120, y=40)

    #  Creating an Entry box for the following
    username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_login_entry.pack()

    #  Creating a label and packing it
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    login_password = Label(login_screen, text="Password: ")
    login_password.pack()
    login_password.place(x=120, y=80)

    #  Creating an Entry box for the following
    password_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify, show='*')
    password_login_entry.pack()

    #  Creating a label and packing it
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", bg="lightgreen", width=10, height=1,         
    command=login_verify).pack()


#  Creating a register user function
def register_user():
    #  Specifying what data to get and store in the following
    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    #  Specifying what we are doing with the file and what mode
    file = open(username_info, "w")
    file.write(username_info + "\n")
    file.write(password_info)

    #  Closing the file
    file.close()

    #  Cleaning fields
    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    #  Showing a success registration message
    Label(register_screen, text="Registration Completed", fg="green", font=("calibri", 10)).pack()


#  Creating a login verify function
def login_verify():
    #  Specifying what data to get and store in the following
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()

    #  Cleaning fields
    username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_login_entry.delete(0, END)

    #  Working with os module
    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    #  Calling a login_success function if username in list_of_files otherwise password not 
    recognised
    #  and calling user not found function
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            login_sucess()
        else:
            password_not_recognised()
    else:
        user_not_found()


#  Creating a login success window
def login_sucess():
    #  Globalising it
    global login_success_screen

    #  Defining the following
    login_success_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    login_success_screen.title("New Page")
    login_success_screen.geometry("450x250")
    login_success_screen.configure(bg="lightblue")

    #  Creating a label
    menu_button = Label(login_success_screen, text="Menu: ")
    menu_button.pack()
    menu_button.place(x=55, y=5)

    weather_button = Button(login_success_screen, text="Twitter Login", command=twitter_details, 
    height="1", width="15")
    weather_button.pack()
    weather_button.place(x=20, y=25)


#  Creating a password not recognised window
def password_not_recognised():
    #  Globalising it
    global password_not_recog_screen

    #  Defining the following parameters
    password_not_recog_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    password_not_recog_screen.title("Success")
    password_not_recog_screen.geometry("150x100")

    #  Creating a label and a button
    Label(password_not_recog_screen, text="Invalid Password ").pack()
    Button(password_not_recog_screen, text="OK", command=delete_password_not_recognised).pack()


#  Creating a user not found function
def user_not_found():
    #  Globalising it
    global user_not_found_screen

    #  Defining the following parameters
    user_not_found_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    user_not_found_screen.title("Success")
    user_not_found_screen.geometry("150x100")

    #  Creating a label and a button
    Label(user_not_found_screen, text="User Not Found").pack()
    Button(user_not_found_screen, text="OK", command=delete_user_not_found_screen).pack()


#  Creating a delete password not recognised and destroying the window specified
def delete_password_not_recognised():
    password_not_recog_screen.destroy()


#  Creating a delete user not found screen and destroying the window specified
def delete_user_not_found_screen():
    user_not_found_screen.destroy()


#  Creating a main page window
def main_account_screen():
    #  Globalising it
    global main_screen

    #  Defining the following parameters
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("450x200")
    main_screen.title("Login/ Register")

    #  Creating labels and buttons
    Label(text="Select Your Choice", width="300", height="1", font=("Calibri", 12)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Login", bg="lightgreen", height="1", width="20", command=login).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Register", bg="lightyellow", height="1", width="20", command=register).pack()

    picture = PhotoImage(file="main picture.png")
    photo_label = Label(main_screen, image=picture, height="75", width="75")
    photo_label.pack()
    photo_label.place(x=30, y=45)

    #  Calling a function
    main_screen.mainloop()


def twitter_details():
    global twitter

    twitter = Tk()
    twitter.geometry("450x200")
    twitter.title("Login Twitter Page")
    twitter.configure(bg="lightblue")

    global ps_verify
    global us_verify

    global tw_u_log
    global tw_p_log

    ps_verify = StringVar()
    us_verify = StringVar()

    username_label = Label(twitter, text="Username:")
    username_label.pack()
    tw_u_log = Entry(twitter, textvariable=us_verify)
    tw_u_log.pack()
    password_label = Label(twitter, text="Password")
    password_label.pack()
    tw_p_log = Entry(twitter, textvariable=ps_verify, show='*')
    tw_p_log.pack()

    tweeter_button = Button(twitter, text="Login", command=call)
    tweeter_button.pack()

    twitter.mainloop()


#  Keeping the window open
main_account_screen()
```

Comment: `val` is an _object_, not a _string_.

Comment: Change `TwitterBot(us_verify, ps_verify)` to `TwitterBot(us_verify.get(), ps_verify.get())` inside `call()`.

Comment: i did this before but all it does when I run it, is that it leaves the username field in twitter login page as blank and then moves to password and does nothing for infinity. :(

Comment: It works fine for me.  See [simple example](https://pastebin.com/wFHChNig) based on your code.

Comment: Appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the `StringVar()`, you need to get the text of the variable, so use `len(variable.get())`.